# Using puppeteer, on TimeoutError screenshot the current state

Tags: timeout, puppeteer

I'm trying to screenshot a website using puppeteer, and on slow sites I receive a `TimeoutError`.

In this case, I'd like to get the screenshot of the current page state - is this possible? if so, how?

Code sample:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let url = "http://...";
let timeout = 30000;
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page
        .goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: timeout}).then(async () => {
            await page
                .screenshot({path: 'example.png'})
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.name === "TimeoutError") {
                // -----> calling await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'}) gets stuck
            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }

        });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `browser.close` when using puppeteer in development, as this may cause the browser closed and puppeteer crashed.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

let url = "https://www.tokopedia.com"
let filename = 'timeout.png'
let timeoutNum = 30000

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const [page] = await browser.pages ()

    page.setViewport ({ width: 1366, height: 768 })

    try {
        await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: timeoutNum}).then(async () => {
            await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png', fullPage: true })
        })
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === "TimeoutError") {
            console.log (error.name)
            console.log (`Screenshot saved as ${filename}`)
            await page.screenshot({ path: filename, fullPage: true })
        } else {
            console.log (error)
        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: Solve with this solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Please accept this as the right answer then.
With my pleasure.